# How can this code make buffer overflow

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webgl

Chrome Version 51.0.2704.84

On gl.bufferSubData line, chrome says:

```
WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: bufferSubData: buffer overflow
```

Note, that I trace the length of VBO with maxAmountWritten variable. I even make it 1 element longer, when I set it's size with bufferData. And thus it's impossible that subBufferData can write over the VBO's edge.

Actual code:

```
updatePlacementVBO() {
    var gl = this.sceneApi.getGlContext();

    var paramsVbo = this.placementVBO;
    if (!paramsVbo) {
        paramsVbo = gl.createBuffer();
        this.maxAmountWritten = 0;
    }
    var written = 0;
    var permanentBuffer = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < this.mdxObjectList.length; i++) {
        var mdxObject = this.mdxObjectList[i];
        if (!mdxObject.getIsRendered()) continue;

        var placementMatrix = mdxObject.placementMatrix;
        var diffuseColor = mdxObject.getDiffuseColor();
        for (var j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
            permanentBuffer[i*20+j] = placementMatrix[j];
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            permanentBuffer[i*20+16+j] = diffuseColor[j];
        }

        written++;
    }

    if (written>0) {
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, paramsVbo);
        if (written > this.maxAmountWritten) {
            permanentBuffer[permanentBuffer.length] = 0;

            var typedBuf = new Float32Array(permanentBuffer);
            gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, typedBuf, gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);

            this.maxAmountWritten = written;
        } else {
            gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, new Float32Array(permanentBuffer));
        }
    }
    this.placementVBO = paramsVbo;
    this.lastUpdatedNumber = written;
}
```

I'm out of ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like paramsVBO is the bound buffer when that else statement is called and there is no call to bufferData to initialize that buffer target with any information

see [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/bufferSubData) for info on creating buffers. other than that it looks like you're on the right track, just that buffer isn't being initialized (at surface glance anyway)

edit: maybe also give [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/getBufferParameter) a try to introspect into the buffer, make sure it's the right size and see how much is being used

gl.getBufferParameter(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, gl.BUFFER_SIZE);

Comment: Thanks. Your answer made me realize I was using "i" as index inside loop instead of "written" variable. Case closed.

Answer (score 0):

I hit a buffer overflow because I initialized a buffer as a `Uint8Array()` array then replaced that buffer with a `Float32Array()`